# Number of object is only one while adding multiple imageview frames

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsvalue

i m new to ios 
I am using a nsvalue to get frame of image view in a Array. but when i log the count of array it says only 1. 
I am using this array to somewhere else to retrieve the frames. 
Can you please tell me how i can get the array count as the number of image views number.

```
int j;
for (j=0; j<6; j++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [_imageArray objectAtIndex:j];
    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:imageView.frame]];
    NSLog(@"%d",[array count]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are re-allocating (thus clearing all it's contents) your `array` each time you go trough the loop.

```
array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

int j;
for (j=0; j<6; j++)
{
    UIImageView *imageView = [_imageArray objectAtIndex:j];

    [array addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:imageView.frame]];
    NSLog(@"%d",[array count]);
}
```

Comment: Some times one just needs a second pair of eyes, that's it :)